# Applying Inverse Function Theorem to prove a function in one variable is bijective.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be such that $g'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$. I want to prove that this implies $g$ is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}$ onto $g(\mathbb{R})$.

I've tried (fruitlessly) to apply the Inverse Function Theorem (IFT), to get "global" bijectivity. However, as I am sure everyone knows, this is hard to do because the IFT is a local theorem and one can't, except in extremely special cases, use it to prove anything global.

The hypothesis of the IFT certainly holds at every point in $\mathbb{R}$ since $g'(x) \neq 0$ for all $x$, i.e., the differential of $g$, $$d g (x) : u \mapsto g'(x) u$$ will be bijective.

**My question:** *Is there a way to prove proceed with this information? If not, what is the right direction to work in?*

**Update:** The responses are interesting. This is actually an exercise from Bartle, so I doubted what he was asking the reader to prove was, in fact, wrong. I didn't even try to think of counterexamples. Thank you for the input.

Comment: Not sure, but the obvious way to prove $1-1$ is with the mean value theorem...

Comment: You can get bijective if there exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that $g'(x)>\epsilon$.

Comment: I missed the onto $g(\mathbb{R})$ part, which is essentially saying that it is injective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $$
g(x) = \frac x{1+|x|}
$$
is not onto.

[image]

---

With the edit, you only have to prove that $g$ is into (the onto part is done, by definition).

As $g'$ never change its sign (because of the [Darboux theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))), $g$ is monotonic. Hence into.

Comment: +1 Might not be differentiable at $0$, but you can certainly find a similar function, like $\arctan x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it *is* differentiable in 0. Because $g(x) = x+o(x)$ around $0$, the derivative is $1$.

Comment: Ah, I was just basing it on the graph, and the intuition about $|x|$ being problematic, but I see the graph is non-uniform - the $y$-accis is different from the $x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes, I wanted to show that the function was increasing up to a constant (without using transcendental functions like $\arctan$).

Comment: This function isn't onto $\mathbb{R}$, but if you reread my question I ask to prove it is onto $g(\mathbb{R})$. Your function satisfies my conclusion.

Comment: @o0BlueBeast0o this is why there is also the second part of my answer.

Comment: Yeah I saw that after I submitted the comment.

Comment: Since $|g(x)-x| \le |x|^2$, it follows that $g$ is differentiable at $x=0$, with $g'(0) = 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g$ is not injective. Then we have $x_1<x_2$ such that $g(x_1)=g(x_2)$. Then there is a maximum or minimum in $(x_1,x_2)$ at which we would have $g'(c) = 0$, which would be a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks I like the proof, but the nature of the question was to use the inverse function theorem. The motivation is to have an example where the inverse function theorem implies something global.

Comment: Does your version of the IVT require $g$ to be $C^1$?

Comment: Yeah, that's the assumption Bartle uses in his proof anyway.

Comment: Hmm, I can think of one approach, but it really is shoe-horning. At any $x$ one can find an open interval $I_x$ containing $x$ and a (locally) injective function $\phi_x$ such that $\phi_x(g(y))= y$ on $I_x$. Then consider $g$ on $[-M,M]$ a compact interval. The $I_x$ form an open cover, so there is a finite subcover. Then $\phi_x$ agree on overlaps, so we can define a $\phi$ on all of $[-M,M]$ which satisfies $\phi(g(y)) = y$. Hence $g$ is injective on $[-M,M]$. But this is a pretty awkward argument.